# Can we use detox tool in Android and iOS native apps? (Not React Native)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, automation, detox

We are currently using Appium for our mobile app testing (Android and iOS native apps) but the tests are a bit flaky so we came across Detox. However it's not clear whether Detox could be used for Native apps as the documentation mentions only React Native apps.

Would the tool work for native apps as well?

Even if it works is it worth spending time on Detox rather than Appium? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Detox on iOS fully supports native apps. This is tested by me consistently. On Android, it should also be supported, but you might run into edge cases where we assume there is React Native. Try it, and let us know if you find issues.

Comment: Is there any issue with native android app? I am exploring detox for app having both native and reactnative screens